# How do I find the regular expression for- All binary numbers greater than 110011

Tags: regex, binary, binary-data, lexical-analysis

I am trying to solve a problem set to practice for an exam. How can I approach questions like these ? Is there a way to verify solutions or is it just trial and error ?

Comment: What's your question

Comment: I am trying to find the regex that represents " All binary numbers greater than 110011"

Comment: SO is a site for *programming* questions, so you are going to get answers about programming from programmers, most of whom have experience with regex libraries. I think you are looking for an answer related to mathematical regular expressions, so the typical responses you will get here might not be that useful to you. Consider asking in [math.se] or [cs.se] but make sure to read the help pages on each site about appropriate questions.

Answer (score 0):

This one seems quite simple: the string has to be one of:

- 1 followed by at least six more characters.
- 111 followed by at least (or exactly) three characters
- 1111 followed by at least (or exactly) two characters.

If the input can start with leading 0s, change all the leading "1"s to "0*1". In any case, it can be factored out.

The answer to your question, "is there a simple algorithm which can do that for me?" is probably "no". But the above is more simple logic than trial-and-error. Writing down random regular expressions until you find one which works is not a good way to solve the problem, given the difficulty of algorithmically proving correctness.